# Powerbi data import not correct

Tags: powerbi

When I import the data from the database "Firebird", I find that some fields are filled with values knowing that in the database these fields are empty.
it sets the value of the previous line.

[image: 1]

Comment: What sort of database are you importing from? MySql, SQL server etc? Its non displayable characters, like a line or carriage return.

Comment: I use the database Firebird. power bi changes the empty fields by values of the preceding field.